# Passing values through Ajax to Controller MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Just trying to make a simple pass with Ajax. Values artID and v are giving the correct values. Get Ajax error every time.

Controller = Article
Method = SaveRating

Ajax code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Url.Action("SaveRating","Article")',
                data: {
                    articleID: artID,
                    rate: v
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {

                        alert("success");

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public static int SaveRating(int articleID, int rate)
    {
       ....
    }
```

Comment: what are `artId` and `v`? are they variables?

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
public class Rating
{
   public int ArticleID { get; set; }
   public int Rate { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public static int SaveRating(Rating rate)
{
   //
}
```

**Client side post**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Article/SaveRating", 
        data: JSON.stringify({ rate:
           ArticleID: "1",
           Rate: "4"
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {

            alert("success");

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following ajax call,

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "/Article/SaveRating",
          data: { articleID: '1', rate: '5' },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) { alert(response); },
          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert data into json string by JSON.stringify then send that data.

```
 var data = {
        articleID: 1,
        rate: 5
    };
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Article/SaveRating',
        data:data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {

            alert("success");

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL isn't correct, change it to `'@Url.Action("SaveRating","Article")'` :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveRating","Article")',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        articleID: artID,
        rate: v
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {

        alert("success");

     },
     error: function () {
         alert("fail");
     }
});
```